# CSS div that appears when hovering on anchor; keeping it visible while hovering over div

Tags: css, hover

I have a div that I want to pop up when I hover over the link before it. The hover works great, but there is a link inside the div that appears that I want people to be able to click but it disappears when I try to go to it.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8QWY/2/)

I am trying to use just CSS here but if I need any jquery or anything then cool.

```
#soldoutinfo a {                                        
    padding:4px 2px;
    font-size:10px;
}

#soldoutinfo, .soldout {                                        
    display:inline;
}

#soldoutinfo a {                                    
    color:#cc0000;
}

#soldoutinfo a:visited {                            
    color:#cc0000;
}

#soldoutinfo + div {                                    
    display:none;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
}

#soldoutinfo:hover + div {                          
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    width:250px;
    background:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #888888;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px;
    top: 19px;
    left:12px;
    z-index:1000;
}

#soldoutinfo + div p {                          
    font-size:12px;
}

<p id="soldoutinfo">
    <sup><a>?</a></sup>
</p>
<div>
<p>Hope is not lost! <a href="#">Send us a message</a> and we will see if our stores have any in stock to ship to you.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: test it with jquery(if s/he hover the ? the style should be  display:show end if s/he leaves this div the style should be display: none or hide. I don't think that this will works only with css.

Comment: Oh ok. I sadly am not very good with jquery at all but I'll check out other posts or something to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the hover effect is on the element after the anchor. So when you leave the anchor, your hover effect will end to.

You could fix it like this, although it's not the cleanest solution:
Set your tooltip inside your anchor, using a `span`

```
<p id="soldoutinfo">
    <sup><a>?</a></sup>
    <span>Hope is not lost! <a href="#">Send us a message</a> and we will see if our stores have any in stock to ship to you.</span>
</p>
```

```
#soldoutinfo span {                                 
    display:none;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    position:absolute;
}

#soldoutinfo:hover span {                           
    display:block;
    height:60px;
    width:250px;
    background:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #888888;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px;
    top: 19px;
    left:12px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/s8QWY/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Edited your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s8QWY/6/

See if this works for you. Basically what I did was this:

1. Make the hidden div be inside the div that you have to hover over to get it to show.
2. Make the position of the parent div relative
3. Make the position of the shown div be over where the hovered element so that the div still shows when you hover over the div itself.

   ```
   <div id="soldoutinfo"><sup><a>?</a><div><p>Hope is not lost! <a href="#">Send us a message</a> and we will see if our stores have any in stock to ship to you.</p></div></sup></div>


   #soldoutinfo a {                                        
       padding:4px 2px;
       font-size:10px;
   }

   #soldoutinfo, .soldout {                                        
       display:inline;
       position: relative;
   }

   #soldoutinfo a {                                    
       color:#cc0000;
   }

   #soldoutinfo a:visited {                            
       color:#cc0000;
   }

   #soldoutinfo div {                                  
       display:none;
       width:0;
       height:0;
       position:absolute;
   }

   #soldoutinfo:hover div,
   #soldoutinfo div:hover {                            
       display:block;
       height:60px;
       width:250px;
       background:#ffffff;
       box-shadow: 0 0 4px #888888;
       position: absolute;
       padding: 8px;
       top: 3px;
       left:3px;
       z-index:1000;
   }

   #soldoutinfo + div p {                          
       font-size:12px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here a approach point:

When you hover the `?`

```
$("#id").hover(function(){
   $(this).find("#toShow").show();
}
```

and when he leaves the `#toShow`

```
$('#toShow').mouseout(function() {
   $('#toShow').hide();
});
```

Comment: fix that comment pls xD

Comment: My bad. I thought I could use the same stuff in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I see no JS code in this fiddle I don't know why. But solution to you would be to use `setTimeout();` in this function you can specify after what period of time after hover the box should be hidden. You can also add to `hide()` param 'slow'.

You can also use ready solution which is [Jquery UI ToolTip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)